# Weird behaviour with vertically+horizontal centering a DIV element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to vertically and horizontally align a div on a webpage. This gets asked quite often and I Google all my problems, however whatever I try and copy code from others, I can't get mine to work, the div just floats somewhere outside the website. As far as I understand it the parent DIV needs relative positioning and the child DIV needs an absolute positioning. Got the following from CSS-Tricks for the child DIV (negative margins are exactly half the height and width):

```
width: 850px;
height: 400px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
margin-left: -425px;
margin-top: -200px;
```

Check my [test site](http://ortrading.com) ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malachute/7TuVm/)) for the example. Anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

get rid of:

```
margin-top: -200px;
margin-bottom: -200px;
```

in the content div. Is that what you mean?

Comment: My bad here, the website still had the old stylesheet. Everything should be in sync now. Though removing it does not help.

Comment: on your JS fiddle, when i remove the negative margins, your red box with white text becomes centered in the view box?

Answer (score 0):

Your container does not really have a height

See this for example

http://jsfiddle.net/7TuVm/3/

I set the height to 2000px you have to scroll down to see your box

```
height: 2000px;
```